# Can't call a local variable assigned in a parent scope

Tags: ruby, scope, local-variables

```
blah = 10
def what?
  "#{blah}"
end
puts what?
# =>
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `blah' for main:Object
#     from (irb):3:in `what?'
#     from (irb):5
#     from E:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/irb:12:in `<main>`
```

Why? What is the right way to write this? Should I just duplicate a variable inside a local scope or is there a better variant?

Comment: See my comment bellow, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Ruby sees a `def` keyword, it changes scope.  The `blah` variable has local scope outside of the method, and so if you were wanting to use that value, you would need to pass it in.

You could change the `blah` variable to be an instance variable, and it would be in the scope of the method as it is written.

It is likely better to pass in a local variable than to change the scope of the variable.

The method name has a question mark which generally denotes a 'Boolean' value.  Though not strictly dictated, that would be a return of `true` or `false`, though you will see it used when it returns `nil` or a *truthy* return.

Your code might be best written like this:

```
def what(blah)
  blah
end
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: To address the parent variable, we need to introduce a parent relationship.

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ParentBlah
  def initialize
    @blah = "Blah"
  end
end

class ChildBlah < ParentBlah
  def use_parent_variable_sorta
   "@blah = #{@blah}"
  end
end

childblah = ChildBlah.new
puts childblah.use_parent_variable_sorta
```

Now we can talk about why local variables aren't able to be used, and that is strictly a matter of scope.  In order to do what we did here we needed to create variables in the same scope.

Why is this done?  Because logic outside of the object doesn't need to be inherently known by the object.  When it does need to be known, then only the value will be introduced via an argument, or the scope will need to be changed.  We tend to think that if the scope needs to be changed for this purpose there might be something else going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know about code convention in Ruby, and I know about solution of this problem (this is kinda academic example).

Comment: The main question is:
Why doesn't Ruby allow use parent scope for variables in string interpolation, but allows use methods in parent scope?

Why did Ruby choose this way of language design?

Comment: (Sorry, I've forgotten add notification)

Answer (score 5):

you need instance variable or method defined here:

```
@blah = 10
def what?
  "#{@blah}"
end
```

or like this:

```
def blah
  10
end

def what?
  "#{blah}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, please, see my comment bellow.

Answer (score 2):

blah is your local variable;
What you can do make an instance variable or to make a global variable you have use "$" sign before variable as explained below

First you can check the scope of your variable as follow

```
blah = 10
defined? blah
```

**Result => "local-variable"**

To make blah as a global variable you can do

```
$blah = 10
defined? $blah
```

**Result => "global-variable"**

```
def what?
  puts "#{$blah}"
end
```

And then call the method

```
puts what?
```

**Result would be 10**